# How can I correctly make this http request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, curl

Recently I stumble across this [SimplePush.io](https://simplepush.io/) wich is perfect for a project of mine, so basically it works perfect via curl as stated on the website:

```
~ $ curl 'https://api.simplepush.io/send/HuxgBB/Wow/So easy'
```

or

```
~ $ curl --data 'key=HuxgBB&title=Wow&msg=So easy' https://api.simplepush.io/send
```

So i'm trying to use it in my server-side application on **NodeJS** but I tried many and many ways without success..

So I was wondering if anyone out there could help me out to acomplish this with a bit of code. Many thanks in advance

I'm not gonna post any code I made because are all wrong and I don't know where to start

Comment: did the below work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, install the npm `request` module.

`$ npm install request`

Then in your node file:

```
var request = require('request');
request('https://api.simplepush.io/send/HuxgBB/Wow/So easy', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
})
```

Comment: @FabioEnne just a simple `GET` request in `node`. Easy when you know, and you will from now on :-) Good luck with whatever you are making